# Copy everything in a subdirectory across to the relevant subdirectory elsewhere

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, cp

At the moment I'm doing:

```
for i in mdx/[0-9][0-9].png; do cp $i ../../d_s_c/images/mdx ; done
```

But as well as the directory `mdx`, I also have other directories called `ntt`, etc.

How can I say 'For everything in a subdirectory, copy it across to the same subdirectory over at at `../../d_s_c/images`'?

Comment: Bonus points for 'copy if file has changed or does not exist in destination, leave otherwise'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to copy things that have changed or are new, you'd be better off using [rsync.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) To cover your other subdirectories, presuming you don't want everything.

```
MYLIST="mdx ntt etc"
for j in $MYLIST
do
        rsync -aq --include='[0-9][0-9].png' --exclude='*' ./$j/ ../../d_s_c/images/$j/ ; 
done
```

If you want to see what it's doing, you can substitute v for q in the parameters. I think this should work for you, you may have to make some adjustments for your environment.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, and I've learned something today, thank you!